# What is the difference between <img> and <Image> layout properties in NextJS?

Tags: css, checkbox, next.js

I  have been working on some custom checkboxes and ran into an unusual feature -
the only way positioning stacks them up is if '.init' and '.hover' are assigned to imgs,
and the only way the '.done' class is displayed is if it's assigned to Image.

JSX code

```
    <div  className={styles.container}>
      <input className={styles.ckb} type="checkbox" name="vt" id="ckb"/>
      <label htmlFor="ckb">
        <img src="VT/vt-.svg" height={88} width={88} className={styles.init}/>
        <img src="VT/vt.svg" height={88} width={88} className={styles.hover} />
        <Image src="VT/vtD.svg" height={88} width={88} className={styles.done} />
       <span className={styles.lab}>: VEGE :</span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

and CSS

```
`
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.init {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
.hover {opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

.done {opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'].ckb {
opacity: 1;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
}

input[type='checkbox'].ckb:hover + label .hover {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
    }

input[type='checkbox'].ckb:checked + label .done {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
    }
`
```

This begs the question - how come?

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, the img element is a standard HTML element that is used to display an image in a web page. The Image component, on the other hand, is a custom component provided by the Next.js framework for handling image rendering.

One of the main differences between the two is that the Image component allows you to specify the desired width and height of the image, as well as a number of other options for controlling how the image is displayed. For example, you can use the src prop to specify the source of the image, and the alt prop to provide an alternative text description of the image for screen readers. You can also use the layout prop to specify how the image should be sized and positioned within the layout of the page.

In contrast, the img element does not have these additional props and options. It simply displays an image using the src attribute to specify the source of the image and the alt attribute to provide a text description.

Example:

```
  <Image
    src="/static/image.jpg"
    alt="A description of the image"
    width={400}
    height={300}
    layout="responsive"
    quality={75}
    loading="lazy"
  />
```

Comment: Davide, have you at least try to read my post? I am asking as you did not address any of the specific issues...